# Saving html and inline styles - created by jquery ui draggable and resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I created a layout builder using jQuery UI, it allow users to resize/ rotate / drag and change basic styles( background color, font size, etc) of selected element.

the elements included are: images, div, spans and svg.

my query is what would be correct approach on  saving this to the server side:

1. Upon user clicking save, grab the content using `.html()` and place it in hidden `textarea`, once ready post the content to server using ajax.  but not sure if there are any limit on the size or  amount of data submitted this way.
2. Save each element status individually (bit more complex, there can be few hundreds of elements) , will send `ajax` request every time a element is created or edited.
3. other options...?

thanks,

Comment: What's the use of placing it in a textarea..? Are you trying to perform a form submission or something? Why not just send via an ajax POST request?

Comment: @TJ yea i am trying to do a form submission.  i was thinking of sending a `array` of `textarea` with `html` in it.  The layout builder can have multiple pages,  hence why i am using `array` of textareas, if u wondered.

Comment: Could be a ton of answers to this. If it were me, I would iterate each of the elements and create an array of objects for each. The object could then contain the attributes of the elements and it's content. This way you reduce the amount of content you have to pass to the server and store in the DB. It might also be helpful to think from the other direction, when you re-draw the elements later. If you're using JQuery like so: `var myImage = $("<img>", { id: "myImgage", src: "/images/myimage.png"});` then you can see how this could be stored and read back.

Comment: @Twisty very interesting  point u make,   i was thinking of creating  a  large `json`   array of all objects. but was confused should i be storing all this in one row in the database or multiple rows  for each object?

Comment: @TheDeveloper that is going to depend on the amount you anticipate. Could go with a single row, yet makes it harder to search if that is needed. If you just have a few elements per page, can make multiple rows, and a table per page. how far down the rabbit hole do you want to go? Look at WordPress or Joomla and how they setup their DB Schema.

Comment: @Twisty thanks for the reply,  since searching is not important, i will keep it simple and use one row approach.  I'm hoping this way the database table  wont  require large storage and have faster performance.  thanks again